# writeLines in R with string

Tags: r, cat

I'm trying to create a data file (`data.file`).

I have a string: `string=c("test1","test2","test3")`    which I need to combine with some other commands and write to a text file. `string` can be of any length.

In this specific case, the output I want in my data file is:
`:   "test1"   "test2"   "test3"   :=`

I tried `cat(':',string,':=\n',file=data.file,append=TRUE)` but this isn't returning the quotation marks that I need.

(It returns `:   test1   test2   test3   :=` which is missing the quotation marks) .

How could I do this? And, can it also be done with `writeLines`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`writeLines` literally just writes lines separated by line separators, nothing more. Formatting has to be done before that.

In order to surround your text by quotes, you can simply do the following:

```
sprintf('"%s"', string)
```

[`sprintf`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/sprintf.html) is a versatile text formatting function (although its usage is quite arcane).

However, there’s a problem if your strings can contain quotation marks. What should happen in such a case? In general, one has to pay close attention to what values are allowed for string content before formatting it, and how to deal with unexpected input.

Comment: So something like this: `writeLines(c(":",sprintf('"%s"', string),":="),con=data.file)` ?

Comment: @James Yes, that would work (but the elements would be on separate lines, unless you set the parameter `sep` to some other value). You can equally use `cat` instead of `writeLines`. Then you don’t need to put the arguments into a vector (so leave off `c(`…`)`).